# Puzzling behavior in simple logical test applied to vector of values

Tags: r

Ok, this has me absolutely perplexed and worried-
As part of a routine, I have been classifying individual observations of variables as `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on whether their values are above or below/equal to the median value. However, I have been getting a behavior in R that is largely unexpected from performing this simple test.

So take this set of observations:

```
data=c(0.6666667, 0.8333, 0.6666667, 0.8333, 0.8333, 0.75, 0.9999, 0.7499667, 0.25, 0.6666667, 0.1667, 0.7499667, 0.5, 0.2500333, 0.3333667, 0.0834, 0.0001, 0.2500333, 0.8333, 0.9999, 0.9999, 0.2500333, 0.2500333, 0.3333667, 0.9166, 0.5, 0.2500333, 0.4166667, 0.0001, 0.1667333, 0.6666333, 0.0834, 0.1667, 0.6666333, 0.9166, 0.1667, 0.7499333, 0.9166, 0.9166, 0.9166, 0.7499667, 0.7499667, 0.4166667, 0.5, 0.2500333, 0.9166, 0.6666667, 0.1667333, 0.25, 0.0001, 0.3333667, 0.0001, 0.25, 0.0834, 0.9999, 0.0834, 0.1667, 0.5, 0.2500333, 0.3333667, 0.9166, 0.9166, 0.8333, 0.9166, 0.75, 0.0834, 0.4166667, 0.5, 0.0001, 0.9999, 0.8333, 0.6666667, 0.9166)
```

For me to classify these values, I did:

```
data_med=median(data)
quant_data=data
quant_data[quant_data>data_med]="High"
quant_data[quant_data<=data_med]="Low"
```

I know there are 1 gazillion ways of doing this more efficiently, but what has me worried is that the output from this does not make sense. Since there are no `NaN`s on the set and the test is all inclusive (`>` or `<=`), I should end up with a list of only `TRUE`/`FALSE` values, but instead I get:

```
[1] "High"  "High"  "High"  "High"  "High"  "High"  "High"  "High"  "Low"   "High"  "Low"   "High"  "Low"   "Low"   "Low"   "Low"   "1e-04"
[18] "Low"   "High"  "High"  "High"  "Low"   "Low"   "Low"   "High"  "Low"   "Low"   "Low"   "1e-04" "Low"   "High"  "Low"   "Low"   "High" 
[35] "High"  "Low"   "High"  "High"  "High"  "High"  "High"  "High"  "Low"   "Low"   "Low"   "High"  "High"  "Low"   "Low"   "1e-04" "Low"  
[52] "1e-04" "Low"   "Low"   "High"  "Low"   "Low"   "Low"   "Low"   "Low"   "High"  "High"  "High"  "High"  "High"  "Low"   "Low"   "Low"  
[69] "1e-04" "High"  "High"  "High"  "High"
```

See the "1e-04"s? What is even stranger, let's pick value 69, one of the ones that return odd values:

```
data[69]
>1e-04
```

If I test this value alone, I get what I expected to get:

```
data[69]<=data_med
TRUE
```

Can someone explain this behavior? It just seems downright dangerous...

Comment: Remove this line: `quant_data=data` and use `data` instead of `quant_data` in the `[. < data_med`, then try your code. You're assigning `High` to a *numeric vector* which replaces it to a `character vector`. Inspect your current output after assigning `High` to understand better what's happening.

Comment: A relatively better way to accomplish this task is using `ifelse` for ex: `quant_data <- ifelse(data > data_med, "High", "Low")`

Comment: I did not remove the quant_data=data or else I have no assigned space for the test, but your second suggestion nailed it- the problem is that once I perform the first logical test, all values in quant_data are assigned as character (e.g., "High" "0.25" "High" "0.1667", "1e-04"). R seems like it will still apply the logical test on character strings that have simple numeric formats, but not on strings with numbers in scientific notation. I almost would prefer it just gave me an error to keep me from doing stupid things like this...

Comment: Thanks Arun! not sure about the down vote, someone must be grumpy

Comment: it's doing the same thing in either case, it's just that the character comparison comes out the way you expect with pure-numeric strings (but even this is probably not guaranteed, depending on locale): from `?"<"`, "Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use"

Comment: @Lucas, avoid phrases like "Erroneous behavior". It's always better to assume that you are making a mistake and not the language.

Comment: I agree with @Roland that this is the probably the language triggering the down-vote, although the text of the post itself is perfectly reasonable (i.e. it's phrased as "I don't understand what's going on", rather than "R must be doing something wrong/stupid")

Comment: Point absolutely taken- Thanks for editing the name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's walk through what you did here.

```
data=c(0.6666667, 0.8333, 0.6666667, 0.8333, 0.8333, 0.75, 0.9999, 0.7499667, 0.25, 0.6666667, 0.1667, 0.7499667, 0.5, 0.2500333, 0.3333667, 0.0834, 0.0001, 0.2500333, 0.8333, 0.9999, 0.9999, 0.2500333, 0.2500333, 0.3333667, 0.9166, 0.5, 0.2500333, 0.4166667, 0.0001, 0.1667333, 0.6666333, 0.0834, 0.1667, 0.6666333, 0.9166, 0.1667, 0.7499333, 0.9166, 0.9166, 0.9166, 0.7499667, 0.7499667, 0.4166667, 0.5, 0.2500333, 0.9166, 0.6666667, 0.1667333, 0.25, 0.0001, 0.3333667, 0.0001, 0.25, 0.0834, 0.9999, 0.0834, 0.1667, 0.5, 0.2500333, 0.3333667, 0.9166, 0.9166, 0.8333, 0.9166, 0.75, 0.0834, 0.4166667, 0.5, 0.0001, 0.9999, 0.8333, 0.6666667, 0.9166)



data_med=median(data)  ## 0.5
quant_data=data        ## irrelevant
quant_data[quant_data>data_med]="High"
```

But by doing this **you have converted quant_data to a character vector**:

```
str(quant_data)
##  chr [1:73] "High" "High" "High" "High" "High" "High" "High" ...
```

Now the comparison between a character value and the `data_med` value is almost meaningless, because `data_med` will get coerced to a character value too:

```
"High" < "0.5"  ## FALSE
"1e-4" < "0.5"  ## FALSE -- this is your problem.
quant_data[quant_data<=data_med]="Low"
```

What you presumably *meant* to do (and a reason to assign `quant_data=data`) was:

```
quant_data[data>data_med]="High"
quant_data[data<=data_med]="Low"
table(quant_data)
## High  Low 
##   35   38
```

As @Arun points out in comments above, `quant_data <- ifelse(data>data_med,"High","Low")` would work too.  So would an appropriate use of `cut()`.

Comment: Actually, `quant_data<=data_med` works mostly. `"0.1" < 1` gives `TRUE`, but `"1e-4" < 1` gives false. So in the former the character is converted to numeric successfully, but it doesn't work with scientific format.

Comment: It's *not* converted to numeric, it's just that lexicographic sorting (see my comment above) happens to give you the right answer.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I am a former student of your UF ecological models and data course.